Handling long-running async AJAX requests in ASP.NET Core MVC with Bootstrap 4.8 and JS
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project with HTML Bootstrap 4.8 and JS.
Some user requests take longer (like 30 seconds or even more) due to the nature of my business. These are async AJAX requests, and while this happens, I do show an animated icon/block at screen. But if the user presses esc, then this icon is removed and user can browse freely again (this also happens if user works in another browser tab).
I was considering to make them async: false so this would make browser unresponsive while waiting for the return. But this is deprecated.
An alternative approach would be to create a backend strategy to hold while that request is being evaluated.
What should I consider?

Considering only the backend strategy, mainly the server-side logic. Avoid the request occupying the main thread. Could push the notice only when task completed, as the consumption of resources is always considered. Prevent user session from expiring.

I have IMemoryCache, I'm considering a bool flag there to check this (since it already checks there for other things)

Since it is already there , it would be a choice not so bad. You only need to consider the persistence in case restart, and customize your error handling steps to make it more friendly.

There are some different choices you could take , e.g. choose websocket to avoid wasting too much bandwidth. Is Ajax necessary or not?

The IMemoryCache is a singleton service because it needs to be always present throughout other services to provide those informations.

And Ajax is there since the beginning of the project, I've never considered replacing it. I will do some researches about replacing it, thanks
